# PHP !_GET displays blank page

Tags: php, html, get

So this is my URL:

http://myawesomesite.com/base.php?file=myawesomefile

and this is my base.php file:

```
          <?php

if (is_file("$_GET["file"].inc.php")) include ("$_GET["file"].inc.php");
else include("homepage.inc.php");

?>
```

This results in a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: `is_file("{$_GET['file']}.inc.php")) include ("{$_GET['file']}.inc.php"`

Comment: This is an *incredibly* dangerous way to code. Please, do something like: `if ($_GET['file'] == 'myawesomefile') { include('myawesomefile.php'); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using double quotes in the `is_file()` function and in the `$_GET` variable. They're in eachothers way.

Use this:

```
if (is_file("$_GET['file'].inc.php")) include ("$_GET['file'].inc.php");
```

Al though I'm not sure but what you have right now should give back an error and not a blank page.